# protocol message diagram - arrow colored

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=12mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[underline=true]{pgf-umlsd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{sequencediagram}
\newinst{ue}{UE}
\newinst[3]{nodeb}{Node B}
\newinst[3]{rnc}{RNC}
\mess{ue}{RRC Connection Request}{rnc}
\mess{rnc}{Radio Link Setup Request}{nodeb}
\mess{nodeb}{Radio Link Setup Response}{rnc}
\mess{rnc}{Establish Request}{nodeb}
\mess{nodeb}{Establish Confirm}{rnc}
\mess{rnc}{RRC Connection Setup}{ue}
\postlevel
\mess{nodeb}{Synchronization Indication}{rnc}
\filldraw[fill=black!30] ($(RRC Connection Setup to)+(0,-.3)$) rectangle ($(Synchronization Indication from) +(0,.3)$)
 node[midway] {L1 Synchronization};
\mess{ue}{RRC Connection Setup Complete}{rnc}
\end{sequencediagram}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it possible assign a different color to pairs of arrows and put a legend with the colors for each protocol layer?

Answer (score 4):

As `pgf-umlsd` uses a `tikzpicture` environment for sequence diagrams, you can simply set the TikZ key `draw=<color>` for the scope of the message in question:

```
\begin{scope}[draw=<color>]
  \mess[<delay>]{<sender>}{<message content>}{<receiver>}
\end{scope}
```

Or if you want to define a convenient macro, you can put this snippet in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{xargs}
\newcommandx\colmess[5][2=0]{%
  \begin{scope}[draw=#1]%
    \mess[#2]{#3}{#4}{#5}%
  \end{scope}%
}
```

which gives you a new macro for messages with coloured arrows in the form `\colmess{<color>}[<delay>]{<sender>}{<message content>}{<receiver>}`.

Answer (score 4):

Package `pgf-umlsd` does not allow to specify the color (nor any other option) of the "messages" (the arrows). However, you can enclose a message or a group of messages in a tikz `scope` and change the color inside the scope, for example:

```
\begin{scope}[draw=red]
  \mess{rnc}{Radio Link Setup Request}{nodeb}
  \mess{nodeb}{Radio Link Setup Response}{rnc}
\end{scope}
```

If you plan to use this construct several times, perhaps a better idea is to define your own `\colormess` to draw coloured messages, using the same trick:

```
\newcommand{\colormess}[4]{%
  \begin{scope}[draw=#1]
     \mess{#2}{#3}{#4}
  \end{scope}
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
\colormess{red}{rnc}{Radio Link Setup Request}{nodeb}
```

Even a better option would be to create a `\mymess` based on the code of the original `\mess`, but accepting also any tikz style to be passed to the draw command:

```
\newcommand{\mymess}[5][0]{
  \stepcounter{seqlevel}
  \path
  (#3)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (mess from) {};
  \addtocounter{seqlevel}{#1}
  \path
  (#5)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (mess to) {};
  \draw[->,>=angle 60,#2] (mess from) -- (mess to) node[midway, above]
  {#4};

  \node (#4 from) at (mess from) {};
  \node (#4 to) at (mess to) {};
}
```

Which can be used like:

```
\mymess{red, dashed, -latex}{rnc}{Radio Link Setup Request}{nodeb}
```

Comment: Hi JLDiaz, the text above the arrow is possible to take the same color?  for example \colormess{red}{rnc}{Radio Link Setup Request}{nodeb}  the arrow red and the text "Radio Link Setup Request" red too

Comment: @user21431 That is the default behaviour, isn't? I tried with last command `\mymess` and worked as you ask.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's true jLDiaz, the behavior of the command mymess do what I indicated. I was checking the command scope, that was just for the arrows. Than you very much for the help!